# Does the Baofeng UV-5R accept both male and female SMA connectors?

Tags: baofeng, connectors, uv-5r

Most antennas for the Baofeng UV-5R have male connectors, but the UV-5R actually has a larger diameter set of threads that look like they'd accept a female connector. Is that true? Is it a female SMA, or some other female connector?

Comment: You ask the question about male vs female for the UV-5R and then you mistakenly state "Most antennas for the Baofeng UV-5R have male connectors".  I own two UV-5R radios.  The antennas without a doubt have an SMA female connector and the radio has an SMA male connector.   Please edit your question so that you do not suppose which answer is correct.  Otherwise your question is confusing and self-contradictory.

Comment: My Baofeng UV 15R is a male on the radio which is annoying as the only other baofeng that has same is the UV3 as far as I can see. I didn't know this until I tried to fit a longer whip which had also a male fitting which would work with most baofengs. Feeling miffed so ordered a converter male to female. At least its cover software wise now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the UV-5R will not accept a female connector. The threads on the outside are for the nut that mounts the connector to the case.

Comment: What do you mean by "mounting washer"?

Comment: It holds the connector to the body of the radio. I guess washer isn't the best way to describe it

Comment: I edited this answer to hopefully clarify, it's not (just) a washer, but maybe better called a "nut" around the outside of the connector. (The other answer has a picture — the nut is the gold-colored ring with four notches in it.)

Answer (score 14):

The Baofeng UV-5R and any other variations in the UV-5R family of radios have an SMA male connector on the radio mating to an SMA female antenna or SMA female adapter.  In the picture I'm holding the anntenna along with the radio so that you can see for yourself which sex connector is on the radio and which is on the antenna. [image]

Comment: The golden colored ring in the image above is the "mounting washer" mentioned in another answer by Richard Hum. This is used for structurally keeping the antenna connector attached to the radio chassis.